# Jetty servlet how to easily manipulate HTML file

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

At this moment I am making my html manually in the java code:

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

    response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello Servlet</h1>");
    response.getWriter().println("session=" + request.getSession(true).getId());

    response.getWriter().println("<body><form method='get' name='App' id='App' action='test?'><fieldset><legend>df</legend><dl><dt><label for='Messages'>Text-Message:</label></dt><dd><textarea id='Messages' name='Messages' rows='5' cols='50'></textarea></dd></dl><div id='submit_buttons'><button type='reset'>Reset</button><button type='submit'>Submit</button></div></fieldset></form></html></body>");
```

Like you can see in the last sentence I am printing out all the necesarry code in order to make my interface.

Instead of writing in that prinln I tried to specificy another file like this to make it easier to change and edit:

```
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("MainPage.html");
    view.forward(request, response);
```

The problem I have is that it can't find my MainPage.html even if I put it in the META-INF (Maven project) folder or add this file to my classpath.

Is there any other way how I could easily make an interface without needing to put it in println's?

Comment: Try put your `MainPage.html` into `WEB-INF` dir. Also read at least about JSP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.html");  
    rd.include(request, response);
```